# Killing xxx because the cloud is no longer accepting new H2O nodes

Tags: h2o, h2o.ai

plz help~

i create h2o-stateful-set which set replicas: 3, then i run a h2o automl job, it works well. but suddenly one of pod breakdown, i use **kubectl delete pod h2o-k8s-1** to delete this pod. the statefulset create a new pod has same name h2o-k8s-1.
But here's the problem, the new pod can't join h2o cluster, and  job stuck, logs as follows

```
FJ-126-3  WARN water.default: Killing h2o-stateful-set-1.h2o-service.dhr-h2o.svc.cluster.local/10.177.5.212:54321 because the cloud is no longer accepting n
ew H2O nodes.
```

i know New H2O nodes join to form a cluster during launch. After a job has started on the cluster, it prevents new members from joining. but what should i do if cluster pod breakdown during training?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected. Once one of the nodes crashes, you will need to restart the whole cluster. You need to make sure that you configure your kubernets jobs so that the pods are not preempted.